# In forgotten password is asking user their TOTP among other details secure?

Tags: account-security, one-time-password, password-reset

I have started to work on the Forgotten password feature on my website. Based on [OWASP Forgot Password cheatsheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet.html), the user should provide enough information to confirm that it is really them.
The system currently is working as follows:

1. The user clicks on `forgotten password` link on the login screen
2. The user fills in a form to confirm their identity (user must enter their username, their email address which is associated with the account, and if the 2FA is enabled for authentication, the user must provide their 2FA token as well)
3. After filling in form the website says "if all data is matching, the email with reset link will soon be on your way." After which the website checks if all data is correct, and if it is, it sends the link with password reset to the given email. (if the 2FA is not set, the TOTP field is ignored)
4. The user opens the link from the email, provides their new password, with confirmation.
5. The password is changed, all current sessions are terminated, user is redirected to login screen, an email is sent to all email addresses linked to the account that the password has been changed.

In the cheatsheet however it appears that when using URL token for password reset, the user should be asked some questions in order to reset their password.
I am wondering if I am introducing some vulnaribility by asking people for TOTP when resetting password. Additionally I am wondering if the process I have outlined is secure.

---

Some more information about the TOTP:

- The TOTP is asked regardless if it is set up or not: the field is optional
- The TOTP on the website is generated only using Authenticator application such as [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2&hl=en_GB), there is no ability to send it via SMS, and the code is not being sent via notification.
- The TOTP can not be removed without user login as well as it *currently* cannot be removed by administrator.

I have been googling for the answer for this question but most of the answers either talk about how to securely remove TOTP, or why using TOTP for generating password reset URL to reduce the length is bad. Neither of those however answer my question.